# Office UI Fabric React - Combobox auto open when freeform==true

Tags: office-ui-fabric, office-ui-fabric-react

Hello I have found that ComboBox component is not opening automaticaly when clicking inside the field when 'freeform' option is enabled - I understand that is by design but is there a way to force it to open even if freeform is enabled - this is my clients requirement at the moment.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the `openOnKeyboardFocus` property? You can find the documentation for it here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/controls/web/references/iselectabledroppabletextprops#ISelectableDroppableTextProps

I tested it in one of their examples: https://codepen.io/alex3683/pen/zYGdyby?editable=true

Comment: Thanks for pointing that place in docs - I didn't dig enough it seems.